# How to assure equal update on 2 tables simultaneously on MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, normalization, data-integrity

I have a problem that is impossible for me to resolve. I am trying to update 2 different tables with the same data but I always end up with discrepancy

I have 2 tables: `users` and `stats`

`users` structure:

```
id: int(25)
balance: decimal(18,6)
```

and `stats` structure:

```
date: date
userid: int(25)
balance: decimal(18,6)
```

I am using innodb transactions to update the tables like this:

```
    mysql_query("BEGIN TRANSACTION");

    $result1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(id, balance)
        VALUES ".$balance." 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE balance = balance + VALUES(balance)");


    $result2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pubday (date, userid, balance) 
        VALUES ".$balance."
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE balance=balence+VALUES(balance)");



if($result1 === false || $result2 === false) {
mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
}else{
mysql_query("COMMIT");
}
```

I am updating the tables at least 5 million times per day. No matter what I always get a minuscule discrepancy between the balance from `users` and `stats` with this queries:

```
SELECT sum(balance) from stats
```

and

```
SELECT balance from users
```

For example I get balance=302.001731 on stats and balance= 302.194501 on users. It should be the same.

My question is what is the error here or what I am doing wrong? Or what is the best way to approach this issue? to update 2 tables simultaneously with the same data.

Comment: You are using unsupported "mysql_" functions and you care about data integrity?

Comment: ....that, and bare string concatenation.  Watch out for SQL Injection!

Comment: I am using PDO, I just wrote it that way to make the example simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple: don't have multiple points of authority.  If the two columns should be the same, *make them the same column*.  I would do this be removing `stats.balance`, and calculating the stats when you need it on the fly through SQL.

After all, ad-hoc queries are one of the core reasons Relational Database Management Systems (RDBMS) were initially researched in the 1970s.

Meanwhile, it looks like you'd like some sort of "Materialized View" so that you can show data from the past.  If that's case, consider saving *each* transaction for a time, and then inserting into the stats table at regular intervals based on SQL calculations.  Something like:

```
INSERT INTO stats (date, userid, balance)
  SELECT CURDATE(), id, SUM(balance) FROM users GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

And possibly, depending on your needs, utilize an UPSERT via `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Obviously, `SUM(balance)` is not complete or correct, but the idea of summation is the point, after you update your schema.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. Just for background this is for an advertising network. Your answer makes sense. We need to display historical data of earnings and we also need to show the balance. We can make as you say and have a single source of truth. Lets say we consider the stats as the only table. Then the balance will be the sum of all earnings. However me need to calculate the balance on every impression. This operation is not as performant as selecting the balance as a single number from table users. Remember we have 5M+ impressions per day and 50k+ users.How should I approach this?

Comment: At some point, given your constraints, you will need to balance performance, correctness, and up-to-dateness. Suggest some cron-like job to update a materialized view every so often, and either simply use the cached value, or calculate the addition based only on the new rows in conjunction with the materialized view's output -- use proper indexes. Some basic math: 10M views (overestimate) in 4-active hours/day is ~700 views a second. Given a beefy server, clever logic preparation and organization (e.g., materialized views), and caching, this is easily in reach on ~2006 hardware.  It's 2017.